# Better way to show a Loading gif for a particular operation

Tags: jquery, popup, gif

I am using `ASP.NET/C#`.In one of my page I am showing list of customers with their details in `ASP.NET Listview`.In every row I have a `Linkbutton` which will show that customer's information in a `popup`.Currently when the `ShowDetails` link is clicked I am showing a `loading gif` and then the information `popup` is displayed.I am using `jquery delay()` to delay the showing of information `popup`.

**Jquery function to show popup:**

```
function ShowCustomerInformationPopUp()
 {
    $('#AuthorizeCustomerLoadImg').show();
    $('#AuthorizeCustomerMask').delay(1200).show("slow");
    $('#AuthorizeCustomerShowCustInfo').delay(1200).show("slow");
 }
```

I am calling this function on click event of `Linkbutton` from `code behind` using `ClientScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript`.So now when the user clicks the `Show Details` `Linkbutton` the `popup` is delayed a bit meanwhile `loading gif` is displayed.So my question is , is it a good way to show the `loading gif` by delaying showing of other element.Are there any downsides to this approach.How do many of you show `gif's`.

Any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a loading gif sparingly.  Which means I would only use it when I'm expecting a call back from the executed procedure. ie. such as an AJAX request.

Since you're opening a new window, I don't see why you would want a loading gif on the opener window, when the new browser window has a `loading` indicator already.

And if you did want to accurately make the gif go away after the popup page loads, then your code for this would have to be placed inside the popup window targeting on the opener window.

EDIT:

Since you've claimed that it is not a new window, then a cool way to do this would be by using a `fadeIn()`, you can also use it on `show()` but i don't think the gif will even have enough time to display if you do.

Anyhow, you would remove your loading gif on the call back, like this:

```
function ShowCustomerInformationPopUp()
 {
    $('#AuthorizeCustomerLoadImg').show();
    $('#AuthorizeCustomerMask').show(1200);

    $('#AuthorizeCustomerShowCustInfo').show(1200, function(){
        // this is the callback function when competed, remove the gif here
        $('#AuthorizeCustomerLoadImg').hide();
    });

 }
```

Not sure which `div` is the suspect here, so you can apply the call back function like above on either one of your `.show()` statements.

Comment: The popup which I am displaying is not a new window , it is a div which I am using.

Comment: Thanks for the help , but I could not understand it properly , are you suggesting me to hide gif when the popup is displayed as your commments suggest.Is it.

Comment: You would hide your loading gif when your process is completed. If you don't understand what the callback is, i suggest you review the documentation here for `.show()`, since most jQuery functions have this feature. http://api.jquery.com/show/

Comment: Ok so I need to hide my gif once the popup is displayed.Right?So do you think I can proceed with what I did.thanks a lot.

Comment: In the callback function I just need to hide the gif right?    $('#AuthorizeCustomerLoadImg').hide();